# Best practices to hide elements on a page

Tags: theming

So at the moment I can use:

- CSS using display: none
- function hide(attribute) using hook_preprocess_page()
- remove title code from page.tpl.php

And I'm sure there are much more! I'm kinda new to drupal so wondering what you guys think is better practice. Ie...

If I want to hide the page title I would use...
If I want to hide the timezone configuration block on user profile I would use...

Thanks!

Comment: Bit of an open ended question...

Comment: To add what Alex Gill said, questions about best practices are usually not constructive. It doesn't also seem you are asking a question based on an actual problem you are facing. What the answer would get is a list of all the possible way to achieve something for which you didn't define any restriction.

Answer (score 3):

As Alex Gill mentioned in the comments this is an open ended question.

My guidelines though are as follows:

- never hide something via CSS if you can hide it via application code, especially if you don't really want it inside the HTML. Hiding stuff with CSS is only acceptable if you want to have them "preloaded" in order to display them later on using javascript
- hiding something via module (e.g code from your features module, if you have one) is good since it can work with any template

In regards to hiding form elements please note that:

- hiding stuff with CSS still makes it possible for "smart" users to alter the hidden defaults, possibly via Firebug etc. So you *should not* assume that users will not be able to alter form elements that they cannot see.
- removing form elements via code may have side effects down the line in case you've removed stuff that is expected in validate functions. E.g if you've removed a mandatory form element then it'll never get submitted.

Comment: Thank you Cherouvim, That was exactly the answer i was looking for. Don't know why others think is not constructive... I mean.. yeah... is not focused on specific problematic, but bad practices are bad practices and for a beginner like me hiding using css is very easy... but now I know is not correct as well.